# Passing static value Value between instance class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms (form1 and form2) that instantiate two object of the new class  containing button and label. I want that when a text label change in one instance both instance are **''refreshed''** with the new text

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    thisclassobjectform newclassform1;
     public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        newclassform1 = new thisclassobjectform();
        this.Controls.Add(newclassform1.BasePanel);
        newclassform1.BasePanel.Location = new Point(1, 1);
        Form2 newForm = new Form2();
        newForm.Show();
    }
}
```

New Class:

```
public class thisclassobjectform
{
    public Panel BasePanel;
    Button newbutton;
    Label Textinit;
    static int i = 2;
    static string txtstring;

   // public static event EventHandler neweventvaluevchange;//with event
  //  public delegate void newdelegatevaluechange(object sender, EventArgs e);//with event
    public delegate void newdelegatevaluechange();//with delegate
    static newdelegatevaluechange thisdelegate;//with delegate
    public thisclassobjectform()//ctor
    {
        BasePanel = new Panel();
        newbutton = new Button();
        newbutton.Text = "click me";
        newbutton.Location = new Point(2, 2);
        Textinit = new Label();
        Textinit.Text = "one label text";
        Textinit.AutoSize = true;
        Textinit.Location = new Point(2, 40);
        BasePanel.Controls.Add(newbutton);
        BasePanel.Controls.Add(Textinit);
        newbutton.Click +=new EventHandler(newbutton_Click);
       // neweventvaluevchange+=new EventHandler(thisclassobjectform_neweventvaluevchange);//with event
        thisdelegate += new newdelegatevaluechange(thisclassobjectform_neweventvaluevchange);//with delegate
    }
    private void newbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtstring = ("some text has changed" + (i++).ToString());
        thisdelegate();//with delegate
        //neweventvaluevchange(this, EventArgs.Empty);//with event
    }
    //private void thisclassobjectform_neweventvaluevchange(object sender, EventArgs e)//with event
    private void thisclassobjectform_neweventvaluevchange()//with delegate
    { Textinit.Text = txtstring; }
}
```

Form2:

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
  {
   thisclassobjectform newclassform2;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        newclassform2 = new thisclassobjectform();
        this.Controls.Add(newclassform2.BasePanel);
        newclassform2.BasePanel.Location = new Point(1, 1);
    }
}
```

I can do that with event (or/and) delegate (which is the same)... but can I do that another way more clean?

Comment: Inside the New class, you can maintain the instance of all objects of the NewClass and update all of them on single update and also make it thread safe if required

Comment: I think it is not "more" clean. The way Jablonovo has done this is good!